# How can I generate a link to the ID of a profile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two controllers- a ProfilesController and a UsersController. I have a page full of blog posts, and I want each to have a link to the profile of the user who created them. I've been having a wee problem with this lately, and I want to start fresh, but don't know where to begin. How can I go about this?

Post controller:

```
 def index
  if params[:search]
    @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
  else
    @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
  end
 end
```

Profiles model:

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Users model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  validates :username, uniqueness: true
  has_many :posts, foreign_key: :author
  has_many :comments, foreign_key: :author
  has_one :profile, foreign_key: :user

  after_create :build_profile

  def build_profile
    Profile.create(user: self) # Associations must be defined correctly for this syntax, avoids using ID's directly.
  end

end

BTW not using Devise
```

Comment: Try getting `@posts` in a console and then `@posts.first.user`. If that returns a user object then you should be able to work out how to get the user for any post, and its properties.

Answer (score 1):

How are your SQL tables? It would be best if your Posts table have a user_id field, that way you could search the user by id (user_id) and process the link via:

```
<%= link_to 'Post Owner', user_path(post.user_id) %>
```

Check to see if it works for you and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, We get object `profile` of each posts like this (you should try it in rails console):

```
@posts.first.user.profile # get the profile of first post
```

After that, we use `profile_path` to generate link to `profiles#show` (Of course, you need to define a controller `Profile`)

```
profile_path(@posts.first.user.profile)
```

I often do it in `view`, not in `controller`.

Happy coding!

Comment: I'm using a @posts.each do |post| loop. Does your answer still hold in this case?

Comment: yes, you can call to `user` via object `post`. (If posts `belongs_to` user)

Comment: It `belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'`